# Using Word2vec output as Input for LDA in topic modelling

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, topic-modeling

I have read that the most common technique for topic modeling (extracting possible topics from the text) is Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA). but recently  I learned about another model lda2vec. However, I am interested in whether it is a good idea to try  Word2Vec output as an input to LDA.

Do you think it makes sense to follow this approach for the sake of some research? As I am doing topic modeling and need some novel approach.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good idea, and there are already some papers. I suggest you search "word embedding + LDA" instead of word2vec. Interestingly, even David Blei himself (the inventor of LDA) said he was considering doing something like this in a [recent interview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/video/fireside-chat-with-david-blei/).